Is it allowed to modify riscv VL register in linux kernel?
I am currently modifying VL register in RISCV arch with vector instructions enabled under Linux kernel, build succeeded, but when running, the kernel panicked about illegal instruction. Is it possible to modify VL register in kernel? What is the right method to modify the VL register?
my code is like this(lines between comments are my newly added codes):
asmlinkage __visible noinstr void do_page_fault(struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    kernel_vector_begin();
    // comment begin
    printk(KERN_INFO " dxt: hello world");
    int vlen = 30;
    
    csr_write(sepc, 1000);
    printk(KERN_INFO " dxt: hello world2");
    //asm volatile ("csrrw zero, sepc, t0\n\r");
    printk(KERN_INFO " dxt: hello world3");
    csr_write(vl, 1000);
    printk(KERN_INFO " dxt: hello world4");
    asm volatile ("vsetvli t0, %0, e8, m8\n\r" : : "r"(vlen));
    printk(KERN_INFO " dxt: hello world5");
    kernel_vector_end();
    // comment end
    irqentry_state_t state = irqentry_enter(regs);

    handle_page_fault(regs);

    local_irq_disable();

    irqentry_exit(regs, state);
}

The output of the startup is like this:
[    1.534451] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[    1.534922] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1 at arch/riscv/kernel/kernel_mode_vector.c:211 kernel_vector_begin+0x4/0x2a6
[    1.536062] Modules linked in:
[    1.536393] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: init Not tainted 6.9.12 #8
[    1.536628] Hardware name: riscv-virtio,qemu (DT)
[    1.536859] epc : kernel_vector_begin+0x4/0x2a6
[    1.536971]  ra : do_page_fault+0x1e/0x9c
[    1.537049] epc : ffffffff80008a72 ra : ffffffff80991db8 sp : ff2000000000bb10
[    1.537093]  gp : ffffffff81508b00 tp : ff600000018a0000 t0 : ffffffff80991d9a
[    1.537135]  t1 : ffffffff80e00ce8 t2 : ffffffff80e00d68 s0 : ff2000000000bb40
[    1.537177]  s1 : ff2000000000bb40 a0 : 0000000000000000 a1 : 0000000000000117
[    1.537225]  a2 : 0000000000000000 a3 : 0000000000000000 a4 : fffffffffffff000
[    1.537269]  a5 : 0000000000000000 a6 : 000000000000d530 a7 : 0000000000000000
[    1.537311]  s2 : 0000000000000000 s3 : 00000000001c8ee9 s4 : 000000000000000f
[    1.537360]  s5 : ff600000018a0000 s6 : 00000000001c2000 s7 : 0000000000000117
[    1.537410]  s8 : 0000000000000000 s9 : 0000000000000001 s10: 0000000000010000
[    1.537452]  s11: 0000000000000002 t3 : ff2000000000ba88 t4 : 0000000000000001
[    1.537491]  t5 : 0000000000000003 t6 : 0000000000040000
[    1.537529] status: 0000000200000100 badaddr: 0000000000000000 cause: 0000000000000003
[    1.537797] [<ffffffff80008a72>] kernel_vector_begin+0x4/0x2a6
[    1.538075] [<ffffffff8099b44e>] ret_from_exception+0x0/0x6e
[    1.538158] [<ffffffff80983b6a>] __clear_user+0x36/0x5c
[    1.538202] [<ffffffff8022e11a>] load_elf_binary+0x386/0x11b8
[    1.538244] [<ffffffff801dfe72>] bprm_execve+0x1e2/0x4ec
[    1.538281] [<ffffffff801e1746>] kernel_execve+0xe4/0x14c
[    1.538316] [<ffffffff80983d10>] run_init_process+0x90/0x9e
[    1.538353] [<ffffffff80983d30>] try_to_run_init_process+0x12/0x3e
[    1.538391] [<ffffffff80992e12>] kernel_init+0xd2/0x10a
[    1.538428] [<ffffffff8099b562>] ret_from_fork+0xe/0x1c
[    1.538650] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
[    1.539045]  dxt: hello world
[    1.549579]  dxt: hello world2
[    1.549872]  dxt: hello world3
[    1.551632] Oops - illegal instruction [#1]
[    1.551673] Modules linked in:
[    1.551833] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: init Tainted: G        W          6.9.12 #8
[    1.551880] Hardware name: riscv-virtio,qemu (DT)
[    1.551899] epc : do_page_fault+0x4e/0x9c
[    1.551937]  ra : do_page_fault+0x4e/0x9c
[    1.551967] epc : ffffffff80991de8 ra : ffffffff80991de8 sp : ff2000000000bb10
[    1.551992]  gp : ffffffff81508b00 tp : ff600000018a0000 t0 : 6c00000000000000
[    1.552017]  t1 : 0000000000000020 t2 : 6c6568203a747864 s0 : ff2000000000bb40
[    1.552042]  s1 : ff2000000000bb40 a0 : 0000000000000012 a1 : ffffffff81485980
[    1.552066]  a2 : 00000000000000db a3 : 0000000000000000 a4 : 0000000000000000
[    1.552091]  a5 : 0000000000000000 a6 : 0000000000000008 a7 : 0000000000000038
[    1.552115]  s2 : 0000000000000000 s3 : 00000000000003e8 s4 : 000000000000000f
[    1.552140]  s5 : ff600000018a0000 s6 : 00000000001c2000 s7 : 0000000000000117
[    1.552167]  s8 : 0000000000000000 s9 : 0000000000000001 s10: 0000000000010000
[    1.552192]  s11: 0000000000000002 t3 : ffffffff8151c957 t4 : ffffffff8151c957
[    1.552217]  t5 : ffffffff8151c958 t6 : ff2000000000b928
[    1.552238] status: 0000000200000100 badaddr: 00000000c2099073 cause: 0000000000000002
[    1.552265] [<ffffffff80991de8>] do_page_fault+0x4e/0x9c
[    1.552302] [<ffffffff8099b44e>] ret_from_exception+0x0/0x6e
[    1.552339] [<ffffffff80983b6a>] __clear_user+0x36/0x5c
[    1.552378] [<ffffffff8022e11a>] load_elf_binary+0x386/0x11b8
[    1.552416] [<ffffffff801dfe72>] bprm_execve+0x1e2/0x4ec
[    1.552453] [<ffffffff801e1746>] kernel_execve+0xe4/0x14c
[    1.552489] [<ffffffff80983d10>] run_init_process+0x90/0x9e
[    1.552527] [<ffffffff80983d30>] try_to_run_init_process+0x12/0x3e
[    1.552564] [<ffffffff80992e12>] kernel_init+0xd2/0x10a
[    1.552611] [<ffffffff8099b562>] ret_from_fork+0xe/0x1c
[    1.552955] Code: 30ef c72f 9073 1412 d517 0062 0513 a545 30ef c62f (9073) c209 
[    1.553495] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
[    1.553876] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
[    1.565423] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt ]---

